# Add Django model property field to model's dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-models

I tried to search elsewhere, but I couldn't find a way to solve it. I can't figure out a way to add the model property to the model's dictionary. Is there a way to do it?
Here's how it is right now, I'm trying to add the property in the natural_key function.

[EDIT] It's going to be used with Django Json serializer.

```
class Departamento(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Departamento'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.descricao

    def natural_key(self):
        return dict(id=self.id, descricao=self.descricao,
                    abreviacao=self.abreviacao,
                    coordenadoria_adjunta=self.coordenadoria_adjunta,
                    ramal=self.ramal)

    def obter_funcionarios(self):
        from modelos.funcionario import Funcionario

        return Funcionario.objects.filter(departamento_id=self.id)

    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    abreviacao = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    coordenadoria_adjunta = models.ForeignKey(CoordenadoriaAdjunta, null=True)
    ramal = models.ForeignKey(Ramal, null=True)
    funcionarios = property(obter_funcionarios)
```

Comment: Have you tried: `def natural_key(self): return self.__dict__()` ?  Model objects are dictionaries, so you should be able to call `__dict__()` on it to return the dict of the object.

Comment: @AronYsidoro A few things wrong with that statement: first of all, models are not dictionaries, it's just that _all_ objects use a dictionary as an internal attribute storage mechanism. Second, `self.__dict__` is just that: a dictionary. Not a callable.

Comment: @knbk you are correct. I could have worded that better. It looks like carloshfoliveira is trying to return a dict of the object, so that was my recommendation.

Comment: @AronYsidoro I tried to call `__dict__()`, but when it comes to use it with the Json serializer, it doesn't work because Django says the given model it's not iterable.

Comment: Is the purpose of this to put the model data in Json?  If so, you can django-rest-framework.  It has that functionality built into it, and should be what you are looking for.

Comment: @AronYsidoro I was afraid of this... I was looking for something that didn't require another pip "/ haha but that's ok. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @carloshfoliveira if that's the functionality that you are looking for and `django-rest-framework` can do it for you then don't reinvent the wheel! It will save you a lot of time to use what is already built!.